# Sprite rotation over sphere

Tags: opengl, rotation, textures, sprite

I have a 2D mode which displays moving sprites over the world. each sprite has rotation.

When i'm trying to implement the same in 3D world, over a sphere, i met a problem calculating the sprite rotation so it will look like it is moving toward the direction. I'm aware that the sprite is billboard only and the rotation will be 2D only, and will not be 100% rotated toward the direction but at least to make it look reasonable for the eye.

[image: The 2D Mode that works fine]
[image: The problem in the 3D Mode]

I've tried to consider the vector to the north (of the world) in my rotation but still, there are allot of cases when we move the camera around the sphere that the sprite arrow is not in the direction of the movement.

Can anyone direct me for a solution ?

-------- ADDITION -----------

More explanation: I have 2D world (x,y). In this world I have a point that moves toward a direction (an angle is saved in the object). The rotations are calculated in the fragment shader of course.

In the 3D world, i'm converting this (x, y) to a (x,y,z) by simple sphere formula.
My sphere (world) origin is (0,0,0) with radius 1.

The angle (saved in the point for the direction of movement) is used in 2D for rotating the texture as well (As shown above in the first image). The problem is the rotation of the texture in 3D. The rotating should consider the point direction angle, and the camera.

-------- ADDITION -----------

My fragment shader for 2D - If it is helping. And few more pictures and my wish

```
varying vec2 TextureCoord;
varying vec2 TextureSize;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

varying float angle;
uniform vec4 uColor;

void main()
{
    vec2 calcedCoord = gl_PointCoord;
    float c = cos(angle);
    float s = sin(angle);
    vec2 trans = vec2(-0.5, -0.5);
    mat2 rot = mat2(c, s, -s, c);
    calcedCoord = calcedCoord + trans;
    calcedCoord = rot * calcedCoord;
    calcedCoord = calcedCoord - trans;

    vec2 realTexCoord = TextureCoord + (calcedCoord * TextureSize);
    vec4 fragColor = texture2D(sampler, realTexCoord);
    gl_FragColor = fragColor * uColor;
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I still don't get it. You have a 3D sphere, a 2D sprite that moves along a 2D path, and a 3D camera. How does the camera affect the path and what does the angle actually represent?

Comment: The 2D sprite location is only X,Y, and this location is updated automatically every 60 milliseconds considering the angle. Then I am converting this location to 3D location with simple calculation. The issue is now the rotation of the texture in 3D. In 2d there was no problem rotating the texture - just cos\sin with the angle and that's it - because it's always from top view. In 3D view it is the problem. There are others factors to consider except the angle of the sprite, like camera i guess, and maybe more.

Comment: And why don't you just draw the sprite in screen space? I see no reason to transform it to world space.

Comment: What does it mean screen space ? I'm not sure i understood you. I have thousands of moving sprites on the 2d world. And when it's in 3D world it is surrounding the sphere.

Comment: The question is why you would transform the 2D sprites to 3D and then from 3D to 2D for drawing. Everything is drawn in 2D (+ depth buffer information). Just draw the 2D sprites as they are.

Comment: In 2D i'm using orthographic projection, and the location of the sprite which is the real earth world (In geographical system) is being used to show one flat image of the world and on top moving sprites. If i will do the same in 3D world, it would just show sphere in the background and sprites on the air. My sprite is single vertex and controling its size with gl_PointSize within the vertex shader. so i am not converting again to 2D. And if i'm just rotating the texture like i did in 2D mode it will always be directed to one direction while the camera is always changing by the user

Comment: The real path of the sprite is 2D. but when converting each location of the sprite to 3D it is a curve around the sphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling allot with this issue I came into this solution.

Instead of attaching as attribute the direction angle to each sprite, I sent the next sprite location instead. And calculating the 2D angle in the vertex shader as follow:

```
varying float angle;

attribute vec3 nextPointAtt;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;    
    vec4 nextPnt = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(nextPointAtt, gl_Vertex.w);

    vec2 ver = gl_Position.xy / gl_Position.w;
    vec2 nextVer = nextPnt.xy / nextPnt.w;

    vec2 d = nextVer - ver;
    angle = atan(d.y, d.x);
}
```

The angle will be used in the fragment shader (Look at my question for the fragment shader code).

Comment: As I said, this is the projection from 3D to 2D space which leads to the question why to use 3D space in the first place.

Comment: Can u explain more what do you mean by 'why to use 3D space in the first place' ?

Comment: You said you have the sprite position in 2D space. Then you transform this 2D position to a 3D position and send it to the vertex shader. The vertex shader projects the 3D position back in 2D space. So the 3D position seems superfluous.

Comment: The 2D position is not screen position. it is world (earth) position. converting it to 3D position in order to see it on the globe (including depth). Then i'm converting it to 2d screen position using the matrices (considering the camera and such) in order to get an angle for rotation the texture. The 2D poisiton after my convert in the shader is not the 2D position i had in the first place.